# Ubuntu 22.04 ACPI BIOS ERROR (BUG)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, nvidia, 22.04

I have just installed Ubuntu 22.04 on an AMD machine running a threadRipper 3960X with a GeForce RTX 2060.

The system is dual boot and upon selecting Ubuntu on grub I get the following message:

[image]

Is this a reason for concern? If so, what can I do to solve it?

Comment: Check your BIOS version with `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`, and then go to the manufacturer's web site and check for a newer BIOS.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the input. 
I updated my bios from version 2.6 to 2.7 but still get pretty much the same error.  https://i.ibb.co/j3t48Xk/Screenshot-2022-05-30-160505.png

Comment: Is this a desktop computer? What brand motherboard? Which Nvidia, and what version driver?

Comment: It is a desktop computer. Motherboard: MSI TRX40 PRO WIFI, GeForce RTX 2060 and nvidia-driver-510

Comment: Besides the Nvidia, do you have any other cards installed?

Comment: sorry for my lack of knowledge, but would you mind clarifying? What other cards would be relevant?

Comment: Any cards plugged into PCI or PCIe slots.

Comment: Any command to check it? I have seen `sudo dmidecode –t slot`but the  output is quite extensive.

Comment: Easiest just to look inside the box. While you check that, boot to a Ubuntu Live USB and see if you get the same errors.

Comment: Sorry, but I have no idea of what is inside! When I put a usb stick, I get the same output [https://i.ibb.co/qY8JLqp/a.png]. If I click on try ubuntu I also get everything yellow [https://i.ibb.co/m5mqbvt/b.png]... But upon installing apart from the error I get everything normal.

Comment: Unplug the computer from AC power. Open the box. Remove, then re-insert, the Nvidia card. Retest.

Comment: Status please...

Comment: Hi, the error persists. After installation there is no difference in color...

Comment: To summarize... the problems occur whether booted to your main hard disk, or if you're booted to a Ubuntu Live USB, yes? The yellow colored screen occurs in both scenarios, yes? You removed and re-inserted the Nvidia card, yes?

Comment: The yellow screen does not occur when I normally boot. Just when I "try ubuntu" in the usb stick. The original image is visible in both usb-stick boot and main drive boot

Comment: Did you remove and re-insert the Nvidia card as I requested yesterday?

Comment: Hi, I have a severe lack of knowldge on hardware. So I did not remove the Nvidia card. Today, I ran a `Windows Memory Diagnostic` and it reported a memory problem. I am sending the machine to warranty!  Thanks for all your effort!

Comment: Status please...

Comment: Hi, the computer went to the seller for a technical evaluation. When I get the report I will fill you in!

Comment: Depending on the report from the seller, please remember to accept my answer, if appropriate, as it called out a hardware problem, and suggested warranty service. Do this by clicking on the checkmark icon that appears just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Status please...

Answer (score 9):

You can get rid of those ACPI Error messages by

1. Open `/etc/default/grub` in an editor with root access. In your case I believe Ubuntu uses gedit as it's text editor:

   ```
    sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
   ```
2. The line with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`, add the `loglevel=3` part. The original looks like

   ```
    GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT='quiet splash'
   ```

Change it to this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT='quiet splash loglevel=3'
```

Then save the changes and close it, now open a terminal and run:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Reboot and see the results

Comment: This actually worked! Woo hoo, confirmed on 2 different machines. These messages started with a kernel update and have been bugging me. You, human being of exceptional merit, are getting a bounty when the system allows.

Comment: thanks sir it is working

Comment: It worked to hide the error message.

Comment: It worked for `Peppermint 11.6 bullseye` based on `Debian`  for `32 bits` too

Answer (score 2):

From the comments...

You have a hardware problem with the i2c circuitry on the **MSI TRX40 PRO WIFI** motherboard (BIOS 2.7), or a hardware problem with the **GeForce RTX 2060** video card.

Contact MSI Support at https://www.msi.com/support, and Nvidia support at https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/support/consumer/, for further assistance.

Or, if the computer is under warranty, contact the warranty provider.

**Update #1:**

Ran a Windows Memory Diagnostic and it reported a memory problem.

**Update #2:**

The computer went to the seller for a warranty technical evaluation.

Answer (score 2):

The ACPI tables in your BIOS are incorrect, and Linux shows error messages during interpretation as it detects the problem.

The tables contain a list of devices in the system, typically those that cannot be found by another method, such as those connected to an I2C bus on the mainboard, as there is no reliable mechanism for scanning an I2C bus.

In your case, there are some duplicate entries, so the second instance is ignored. This probably happened because an older version of the BIOS shipped these entries as part of a supplemental table, and a later version included them into the main table, but the supplemental table was not removed.

These errors should be harmless and can be ignored as long as the system works fine otherwise.

Comment: These errors started showing up after a kernel update. No UEFI update has been done on these machines for years.