# After upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04 recently, I started getting errors after login

Tags: login, 22.04

Ever since I upgraded my Dell XPS 13 from 20.04, I get startup errors when signing in. They disappear from the screen quickly, so I did a journalctl -b and got the following:
ruomini@ruomini-XPS-13-9370:~$ journalctl -b | grep -i "error"

```
Oct 02 21:47:17 ruomini-XPS-13-9370 kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_PR.PR00._CPC], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/psargs-330)
Oct 02 21:47:17 ruomini-XPS-13-9370 kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_PR.PR01._CPC due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210730/psparse-529)
Oct 02 21:47:17 ruomini-XPS-13-9370 kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_PR.PR00._CPC], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/psargs-330)
Oct 02 21:47:17 ruomini-XPS-13-9370 kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_PR.PR02._CPC due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210730/psparse-529)
Oct 02 21:47:17 ruomini-XPS-13-9370 kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_PR.PR00._CPC], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/psargs-330)
Oct 02 21:47:17 ruomini-XPS-13-9370 kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_PR.PR03._CPC due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210730/psparse-529)
Oct 02 21:47:17 ruomini-XPS-13-9370 kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_PR.PR00._CPC], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/psargs-330)
Oct 02 21:47:17 ruomini-XPS-13-9370 kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_PR.PR04._CPC due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210730/psparse-529)
Oct 02 21:47:17 ruomini-XPS-13-9370 kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_PR.PR00._CPC], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/psargs-330)
Oct 02 21:47:17 ruomini-XPS-13-9370 kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_PR.PR05._CPC due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210730/psparse-529)
Oct 02 21:47:17 ruomini-XPS-13-9370 kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_PR.PR00._CPC], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/psargs-330)
Oct 02 21:47:17 ruomini-XPS-13-9370 kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_PR.PR06._CPC due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210730/psparse-529)
Oct 02 21:47:17 ruomini-XPS-13-9370 kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_PR.PR00._CPC], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/psargs-330)
Oct 02 21:47:17 ruomini-XPS-13-9370 kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_PR.PR07._CPC due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210730/psparse-529)
Oct 02 21:47:17 ruomini-XPS-13-9370 kernel: RAS: Correctable Errors collector initialized.
Oct 02 21:47:17 ruomini-XPS-13-9370 kernel: EXT4-fs (nvme0n1p3): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro. Quota mode: none.
Oct 02 21:47:18 ruomini-XPS-13-9370 systemd[1]: Started Process error reports when automatic reporting is enabled (file watch).
Oct 02 21:47:18 ruomini-XPS-13-9370 systemd[1]: Started Process error reports when automatic reporting is enabled (timer based).
Oct 02 21:47:18 ruomini-XPS-13-9370 systemd[1]: Starting Process error reports when automatic reporting is enabled...
Oct 02 21:47:19 ruomini-XPS-13-9370 networkd-dispatcher[1196]: ERROR:Unknown state for interface NetworkctlListState(idx=1, name='lo', type='loopback', operational='n/a', administrative='unmanaged'): n/a
Oct 02 21:47:19 ruomini-XPS-13-9370 networkd-dispatcher[1196]: ERROR:Unknown state for interface NetworkctlListState(idx=2, name='wlp2s0', type='wlan', operational='n/a', administrative='unmanaged'): n/a
Oct 02 21:47:19 ruomini-XPS-13-9370 systemd[1]: Finished Process error reports when automatic reporting is enabled.
Oct 02 21:47:19 ruomini-XPS-13-9370 systemd-xdg-autostart-generator[1460]: Not generating service for XDG autostart app-gnome\x2duser\x2dshare\x2dobexpush@autostart.service, error parsing Exec= line: No such file or directory
Oct 02 21:47:19 ruomini-XPS-13-9370 systemd-xdg-autostart-generator[1460]: Not generating service for XDG autostart app-gnome\x2dsoftware\x2dservice@autostart.service, error parsing Exec= line: No such file or directory
```

and much more.

Comment: This answer stopped the ACPI BIOS errors from displaying for me https://askubuntu.com/a/1425476/243321  (they are meaningless errors due to a kernel bug) I do not know about the other errors.

Comment: The networkd-dispatcher looks like expected behavior because your Ubuntu Desktop networking should be handled by NetworkManager instead.

Comment: That didn't help me; I'm still getting the BIOS errors.

Comment: Yes, I get these:  `networkd-dispatcher[2362]: ERROR:Unknown state for interface NetworkctlListState(idx=2, name='eth0', type='ether', operational='n/a', administrative='unmanaged'): n/a`